# Is it likely as automation continues to make more jobs obselete, starvation and poverty levels will rise very badly?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, inequality, political-economy, poverty

I wanted to know facts, thoughts and such since this article (which was big news that trended this week) popped up: http://www.nbcnews.com/tech/tech-news/robot-may-take-your-job-next-few-years-n499556

I know "History always made NEW jobs when technology advanced...I feel like it's getting so advanced the new jobs, even repairing robots, will be done by robots and that is what is different this time.  When the tractor came along there were no robots just humans to fix it.. I am a writer/journalist. However, these days a pencil and paper aren't enough. To survive we must adapt so I am learning online video and podcasts as well. No need for humans to work=no jobs for humans=no way for most humans to earn money= no way for the humans to feed themselves or their families or even provide warmth. Essentials for just living and not dying in poverty.

I have started learning programming again through Codeacademy and research on Google, plus old books I had from a few years ago. Working on HTML, CSS, JavaScript (taught together) and some Java too. I know having a good understanding and practice of these languages will help me and others adapting to the future, but needless to say some people have it harder than others because of health issues or where they were born into.  Been reading Investopedia.com as well to learn more. The job at a factory assembling or even as a truck driver is all some people have and use to make very good livings from it. With technology advancing in things like robots, computer software and even 3D printers, how exactly will the economy NOT collapse if we keep losing jobs...while still growing in population?

Will it be likely we see increases of starvation, homelessness or communism?

Comment: Sorry if it is opinion based but I feel like from history or basic economics there must be maybe a strategy for this the government is likely to use to avoid a horrible collapse.  Yes?  No?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How will non-rich citizens make a living if jobs keep getting replaced by robots and are outsourced?](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9176/how-will-non-rich-citizens-make-a-living-if-jobs-keep-getting-replaced-by-robots)
and [Has automation of technology shown to have a better impact on the world society and economy or worse one?](http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/9994/has-automation-of-technology-shown-to-have-a-better-impact-on-the-world-society)